# bootstrap form helper phone wont work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, form-helpers

I m trying to make a website using form Bootstrap framework. As part of my code I have

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="inputTell">Telephone</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" id="inputTell" class="bfh-phone" data-format="(ddd) ddd-dddd">
</div>
</div>
```

This is the image:

[image]

It shouldnt be like that. It shouldn't accept any strings and it should give me the phone format like this:

[image]

I already have the necessary JS files in my directory but I am not sure why it is not working.

Comment: Don't you get any error in the js console (Shift+Ctrl+J on Chrome/Firefox)?

Comment: no it doesnt give me any errors, however I think it doest read the CSS file, Its has been linked correctly, when I use inspect element, it doesnt show me the CSS properties. I dont know whats gonna going wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure the input field is inside a form. The phone helper will not work correctly otherwise.

```
<form>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputTell">Telephone</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputTell" class="bfh-phone" data-format="(ddd) ddd-dddd">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjnjv/40/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! The hotlinked bootstrap-formhelpers.js was gone. Now it is working again.

Answer (score 1):

also, the input type must be "text" or "tel" for formhelpers to work:

snippet part from bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js:

```
    ... ('form input[type="text"].bfh-phone, 
          form input[type="tel"].bfh-phone, span.bfh-phone').each(function(){
     ... 
 });
```

may be useful for someone

Answer (score 0):

you've forgotten to add `<form>` tag.

just put your code inside a `<form>` tag, and it will start working.

```
<form>

    <input type="text" id="inputTell" class="bfh-phone" data-format="(ddd) ddd-dddd">

</form>
```

Note: also add necessary classes of bootstrap like controls, form etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've try use type tel and another class

```
<div class="control-group">
   <input type="tel" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-format="(ddd) ddd-dddd" name="number" required>
</div>
```