# Bootstrap form helper phone input converter is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-form-helper

my example as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-form-helpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>

<form class="example form-inline">
<p>Simple example for formatting a phone number in input text</p>
<input type="text" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-format="+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and i read this [bootstrap form helper phone wont work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750053/bootstrap-form-helper-phone-wont-work) but the information is not sufficient

help me.